# How to parse to custom type in Haskell

Tags: string, parsing, haskell, types

I'm new to haskell and have no idea how to parse.

I have created a new type

```
type Field = String
```

Now I want parse [String] to [Field], how could I do this?
I already have this:

```
parse :: [String] -> [Field]
```

Comment: But here you do not parse: a `Field` is a `String`: you have defined a type alias. So that means that `[String]` is `[Field]`. You do not have to do any processing.

Answer (score 4):

> I have created a new type

No you have not. If you write `type Foo = ...` you define a **type alias**: there is no new type, you only have given a certain (composite) type a new name. From now on, you can use `Field` and `String` interleaved. You define new types with `data Foo = ...` or `newtype Foo = ...`. Usually `type Foo = ...` is used to give a more complex type a specific name. Like for instance `type NamedStringCollection = (String,[String])`.

Since `String` and `Field` are the same type, so are `[String]` and `[Field]`. As a result you do not need to do any processing. If you have a `[String]`, this is at the same time a `[Field]`.

You can write:

```
parse :: [String] -> [Field]
parse = id  -- not necessary
```

But the `id` simply returns what you give it. So `id` does not do any work.